# ArcGIS Pro Arcade Expression Attribute Rule: Validation Rule

Tags: arcgis-pro, validation, attribute-rules

I am trying to debug this validation rule where its giving me an error:

"Edit operations failed. The row contains a bad value."

```js
var reason = isEmpty($feature.reason) 
var number = isEmpty($feature.number)
var section = isEmpty($feature.section)
var year = $feature.year

if (!isEmpty(year) && year > 2016){
  if ((reason == True) || (number == True) || (section == True)){
    return False
  } else {
    return True
  }
}
```

Update:

Getting this popup window whenever I evaluate rules. There doesn't seems to be any bad/invalid values in the row though.

[image]

Comment: Could year be empty too? You never test if the value exists.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sample data that generates the error, even if the data is made up and not your actual data.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I would think the isEmpty() function would cater for the expression to only be applied to the non-empty fields.

Comment: It's this that might be the problem - `(!isEmpty(year) && year > 2016)`. If year was empty then the first part should work in that the isEmpty() function returns a True or False and then you compare that with `&& year` and if year is empty then what you have is `True && Null` which is not logical.

Comment: @Hornbydd, if year is null, `year > 2016` returns  "false"

Comment: Although `True` and `False` will work, ArcGIS Arcade convention is for them to be lowercase `true` and `false`.